# mysql query help (merge rows)

Tags: mysql

Due to a bug in a program I've got some semi-duplicate data in my database.  I'd like to merge those records (or delete duplicates).

My data looks like this:

```
usertable:
(userid, username, useremail)
101, joeuser, joeuser@mycompany
102, joeuser, joeuser@mycompany

datatable: 
(userid, datasubmitted)
101, mysubmittedata
102, othersubmitteddata
```

I would like to get rid of any duplicate id's and merge any records for either id into a single userid.

When complete I'd like for the data to look like this:

```
usertable:
(userid, username, useremail)
101, joeuser, joeuser@mycompany

datatable: 
(userid, datasubmitted)
101, mysubmittedata
101, othersubmitteddata
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) and [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) at all?

Comment: Yes.  My problem is how to programatically select and merge rows. There are several thousand so it would be difficult to merge them manually.

Comment: sorry didn't realize there were many duplicate ids in the usertable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Its a two step process

1. fix your datatable first

Update datatable set userid = (select min(userid) from usertable group by username, useremail
    where username=datatable.username and useremail=datatable.useremail)



2. then remove duplicates from user table

delete from usertable u1 where userid > (select min(userid) from usertable u2 group by username, useremail
    where u1.username=u2.username and u1.useremail=u2.useremail)
```